# Filter a large number of IDs from a dataframe Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large dataframe with a format similar to

```
+-----+------+------+
|ID   |Cat   |date  |
+-----+------+------+
|12   | A    |201602|
|14   | B    |201601|
|19   | A    |201608|
|12   | F    |201605|
|11   | G    |201603|
+-----+------+------+
```

and I need to filter rows based on a list with around 5000 thousand IDs. The straighforward way would be to filter with `isin` but that has really bad performance. How can this filter be done?

Comment: if you can partition your data by some means then you should be able to join faster

Answer (score 7):

If you're committed to using Spark SQL and `isin` doesn't scale anymore then inner equi-join should be a decent fit.

First convert id list to as single column `DataFrame`. If this is a local collection

```
ids_df = sc.parallelize(id_list).map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF(["id"])
```

and `join`:

```
df.join(ids_df, ["ID"], "inner")
```

Comment: This does not filter the rows, but gives the entire table