# pyspark - join with OR condition

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark

I would like to join two pyspark dataframes if **at least** one of two conditions is satisfied.

Toy data:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (10, 1, 666),
    (20, 2, 777),
    (30, 1, 888),
    (40, 3, 999),
    (50, 1, 111),
    (60, 2, 222),
    (10, 4, 333),
    (50, None, 444),
    (10, 0, 555),
    (50, 0, 666)
    ],
    ['var1', 'var2', 'other_var'] 
)

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (10, 1),
    (20, 2),
    (30, None),
    (30, 0)
    ],
    ['var1_', 'var2_'] 
)
```

I would like to maintain all those rows of `df1` where `var1` is present in the distinct values of `df2.var1_` **OR** `var2` is present in the distinct values of `df2.var2_` (but not in the case where such value is 0).

So, the expected output would be

```
+----+----+---------+-----+-----+
|var1|var2|other_var|var1_|var2_|
+----+----+---------+-----+-----+
|  10|   1|      666|   10|    1|   # join on both var1 and var2
|  20|   2|      777|   20|    2|   # join on both var1 and var2
|  30|   1|      888|   10|    1|   # join on both var1 and var2
|  50|   1|      111|   10|    1|   # join on var2
|  60|   2|      222|   20|    2|   # join on var2
|  10|   4|      333|   10|    1|   # join on var1
|  10|   0|      555|   10|    1|   # join on var1
+----+----+---------+-----+-----+
```

Among the other attempts, I tried

```
cond = [(df1.var1 == (df2.select('var1_').distinct()).var1_) | (df1.var2 == (df2.filter(F.col('var2_') != 0).select('var2_').distinct()).var2_)]
df1\
    .join(df2, how='inner', on=cond)\
    .show()

+----+----+---------+-----+-----+
|var1|var2|other_var|var1_|var2_|
+----+----+---------+-----+-----+
|  10|   1|      666|   10|    1|
|  20|   2|      777|   20|    2|
|  30|   1|      888|   10|    1|
|  50|   1|      111|   10|    1|
|  30|   1|      888|   30| null|
|  30|   1|      888|   30|    0|
|  60|   2|      222|   20|    2|
|  10|   4|      333|   10|    1|
|  10|   0|      555|   10|    1|
|  10|   0|      555|   30|    0|
|  50|   0|      666|   30|    0|
+----+----+---------+-----+-----+
```

but I obtained more rows than expected, and the rows where `var2 == 0` were also preserved.

What am I doing wrong?

*Note: I'm not using the `.isin` method because my actual `df2` has around 20k rows and I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071095/filter-a-large-number-of-ids-from-a-dataframe-spark) that this method with a large number of IDs could have a bad performance.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the condition below:

```
cond = (df2.var2_ != 0) & ((df1.var1 == df2.var1_) | (df1.var2 == df2.var2_))
df1\
    .join(df2, how='inner', on=cond)\
    .show()

+----+----+---------+-----+-----+
|var1|var2|other_var|var1_|var2_|
+----+----+---------+-----+-----+
|  10|   1|      666|   10|    1|
|  30|   1|      888|   10|    1|
|  20|   2|      777|   20|    2|
|  50|   1|      111|   10|    1|
|  60|   2|      222|   20|    2|
|  10|   4|      333|   10|    1|
|  10|   0|      555|   10|    1|
+----+----+---------+-----+-----+
```

The condition should only include the columns from the two dataframes to be joined. If you want to remove `var2_ = 0`, you can put them as a join condition, rather than as a filter.

There is also no need to specify `distinct`, because it does not affect the equality condition, and also adds an unnecessary step.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Unfortunately, I realised that I had a duplicated row in the desired output (`|  30|   1|      888|   30| null|`), and I don't want that. Also, I would like not to join on null values of `df2.var2_` (they can be treated as the value 0 in my case). How should the code change? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: In that case the code is even simpler where you can just use `!= 0`. See edited answer.