# Standardize large Pyspark dataframe using scipy Z-score

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a py-spark code running in Azure databricks. I have a spark dataframe with 20 numerical columns, named column1, column2, ...column20.
I have to calculate the Zscore(`from scipy.stats import zscore`) of these 20 columns, for that I am reading these 20 columns as numpy array.

But this collect is causing the spark cluster to restart, I understand collect is trying to bring the entire data set into a driver, do we have an alternative approach for solving this problem?

I can increase the driver node memory or I can think of using memory optimized VM for the driver, but do we have an alternative without a higher infra?

Below is the code snippet to create the sample dataframe.

```
import databricks.koalas as ks

    import pandas as pd
    import random
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.stats import zscore
    df = ks.DataFrame.from_dict({
                'Column1': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column2': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column3': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column4': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column5': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column6': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column7': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column8': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column9': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column10': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column11': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column12': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column13': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column14': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column15': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column16': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column17': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column18': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column19': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)],
                'Column20': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(15000000)]   
            })
            df_spark=df.to_spark()
        
        stats_array = np.array(df_spark.select('Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5', 'Column6', 'Column7', 'Column8', 'Column9', 'Column10', 'Column11', 'Column12', 'Column13', 'Column14', 'Column15', 'Column16','Column17','Column18','Column19','Column20').collect()) #causing out of memory error
        normalized_data = zscore(stats_array, axis=0)
        normalized_data_remnan = np.nan_to_num(normalized_data)
        normalized_df = pd.DataFrame(data=normalized_data_remnan, columns=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5', 'Column6', 'Column7', 'Column8', 'Column9', 'Column10', 'Column11', 'Column12', 'Column13', 'Column14', 'Column15', 'Column16','Column17','Column18','Column19','Column20'])
        normalized_df['sq_dist'] = [np.linalg.norm(i) for i in normalized_data_remnan]
```

Is there a better way of doing this without getting all the columns as a numpy array in driver? I would appreciate your suggestions on this.

Comment: df = ks.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'Column1': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(30000000)],
    .......................................
  'Column18': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(30000000)], 
})
df_spark=df.to_spark()
#Gives the error in below  statement
stats_array = np.array(df_spark.select('Column1','Column18').collect())
normalized_data = zscore(stats_array, axis=0)
#converrt nan to 0
normalized_data_remnan = np.nan_to_num(normalized_data)
#Calculate norms 
normalized_df['sq_dist'] = [np.linalg.norm(i) for i in normalized_data_remnan]

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at [Spark UDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html) or [Pandas UDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html) to use external packages' functions on a Spark dataframe. This avoids collecting the whole data into the driver. Furthermore, if you would like assistance by a user, please include a sample of your data as well as your desired output and the attempts you made so far.

Comment: Thanks @RicS . If I use  'Column1': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(30000000)],
    'Column2': [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(30000000)]  upto 20 columns and try to read all these columns in a single statement like np.array(df_spark.select('Column1',.....'Column18').collect()) , I am able to reproduce the error. I have a sample Jupiter notebook which I don't see an option to attach here. I will check the  Spark UDF you suggested, are you aware of any specific external package?

Comment: Also, instead of reading all the 18 columns together, I divided the read statements into multiple groups as ks.set_option('compute.ops_on_diff_frames', True)
  
df['Column1_zscore'] = ks.Series(zscore(df['Column1'].to_numpy()))
df['Column2_zscore'] = ks.Series(zscore(df['Column2'].to_numpy())) , but it did not help either.

Comment: By "include a sample of your data" I mean edit your question and include a few rows (like 3-20 rows) from your dataframe, as if you would create a new dataframe with only those rows thanks to the function `spark.createDataFrame`. Besides, show how your expected output of those few rows would be. To understand what I mean, have a look at this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66687697/pyspark-join-with-or-condition) of mine where the sample data, the expected outputs and my attempts are present.

Comment: @Nikesh your comments here are helpful but could be missed by someone looking at only your question. can you add your comments and code to reproduce your error into the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep all your results in Spark and avoid the `collect` step, you should use a *for*-loop and aggregate functions over the entire dataframe:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy()

for c in df_spark.columns:
  df_spark = df_spark.withColumn(c, (F.col(c) - F.mean(c).over(w)) / F.stddev(c).over(w))
```

In this case I supposed that all your columns needed to be standardized, otherwise specify which columns you need instead of writing `df_spark.columns`.

The empty window `Window.partitionBy()` is needed by pyspark to compute mean and standard deviation on the entire column.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your data as parquet or csv on the hard disk and restart your kernel then load the data outside of pyspark environment. the main problem with .collect is data will be loaded in pyspark and your python at the same time and it will get a huge memory.

Comment: Thanks @Dawyi , that mean I can do a df.persist(DISK only) and proceed? What do you mean by "load the data outside of pyspark environment", apologies for my ignorance.